# How to "Undo" further steps in Final Cut Pro X

Tags: final-cut-pro

I am using Final Cut Pro X version 10.4.8. I need to undo more than 10 steps or even 20 steps backward but the software does not allow me. How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

You can undo whatever you did since the last time you have opened the app. Further than that you will need to get a backup version of that "library" (meaning the file project in Apple's brain) located in your backups folder, defined in the Library Properties panel. Also it is a good idea to snapchat your "projects" (meaning the timeline/sequence) from time to time, so you have older versions.

[image]

[image]